# Extracting copy from screen without printing screen

Tags: printing, scanning, ocr

In preparing academic articles that require quotations from reputable Journals and books I am faced with a round-about retrieval process. First I take a screenshot then print that then scan it and then OCR it into my article document.

Is there a simpler way?

I have an iMac, MS Office and a Canon scanner with My Image Garden.

Comment: Do you have to have it in OCR or just as image?

Comment: Why are you printing and scanning? Can you not use the screenshot in lieu of the scanned image?

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in checking out [Aristocrat](http://joshparnham.com/projects/aristocrat/), a simple app that performs OCR on a selected region of your screen. It's currently [free on the App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/aristocrat/id886910172?ls=1&mt=12).

Disclaimer: I'm the developer :)

Comment: Thanks for self-disclosing. Welcome to Ask Different! Be sure to ask and answer questions that aren't directly related to your product for the best reception from the community.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to make a screenshot.

Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> +  <kbd>4</kbd> to drag a specific selection.

The screenshot will be saved as image file on your desktop.

Comment: I guess this does save the print step :)